# How to use an image for the border bottom in Webkit browsers like Safari?

Tags: iphone, ios, css, mobile-safari

There are a few questions on StackOverflow about how to use border images, but those are fairly outdated.

We have a simple need: to use an image as a bottom border. We only need to support Webkit browsers, specifically mobile Safari.

How can we do this?

Comment: Is this what you mean? http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/

Comment: Yes, but how do you use an image only for the bottom border? It's not clear.

Comment: Assuming you know the answer, can you post as an answer please? Otherwise, we can't award you the points.

Answer (score 1):

For only image to the border bottom, use `border-bottom-image` css3 property.

For only `webkit` browsers,  use the following `-webkit-border-bottom-image`

`mobile safari` [supports](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3031106?start=0&tstart=0) css3.

**Update**:

According to [css3Info](http://www.css3.info/preview/border-image/),

only [`border-image`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image#Browser_compatibility/#Syntax) property works in Safari.

so, [**use**](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-border-image):

```
-webkit-border-image: url(filePath) 0 0 5 0 repeat;  // top, right, bottom , left
 border-image: url(filePath) 0 0 5 0 repeat;  // top, right, bottom , left
```

You may want to check the [compatibility table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-image#Browser_compatibility).

Comment: according to this page (http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-image.asp), the values (5 in this case) represent the width. but we need something to control the height. how do we accomplish this? and shouldn't the width occupy the full width of the border in the first place?

Comment: @Crashalot use `border:5px solid transparent;` before applying it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it's still unclear to me why the values represent width for a bottom border. Shouldn't it represent the height?

Comment: @Crashalot you can set `height` value by simply using `border-width` (or `border`) property. In this `border-image` property, you can arrange the image by setting values  in directions like top, right, bottom and left. If you want to set the image to bottom-left, then give values to bottom and left directions of the property `border-image`.